# Set linkButton att using Jquery in .aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to set link button toolTip att using Jquery, I am using this link button inside a repeater , so I want ti call it by class not by id, so what can do?

```
<asp:LinkButton  class="Edit-icon"  ToolTip=""  runat="server" />
```

```
            $('LinkButton[class]').each(function () {
             this.att("ToolTip","Edit");

          }
          );
```

Comment: why do you actually want to set the tooltip at client side?

Comment: Because I am using multi language site.

Comment: I still don't understand why exactly. You know what language version to render at server side, don't you.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkButton` is not an html tag, it is only use to generate an `<a>` tag.

Try this:

```
$('a.Edit-icon').each(function(){
     $(this).attr('ToolTip','Edit');
});
```

Comment: I can't use <a> because link button perform server side function in code behind

Comment: i think its because ToolTip is not a valid attribute.

Comment: my guess is that ToolTip renders out as something different... i guess `data-something` to be HTML compliant

Comment: You can still use 'LinkButton', you dont have to change it. It will render an `<a>` tag on your page and it will be recognized by your jquery code.